# read local json file in javascript as object to be used in javascript file

Tags: javascript, json

lets say I have a json file with this: (jsonFile.json)

```
{ ["name": "Bobby"], ["name": "Jeoff"] }
```

I want to be able to use a separate .js file to read the data from that file and use it like this:

```
var firstName = (jsonFile.json).name[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's not valid JSON, but what you would do is a request to the local file.

An approach could be:

```json
// jsonFile.json

{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "Bobby"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jeoff"
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
// index.js

fetch('./jsonFile.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data.users));
```

Which would output the array of users: `0: Object { name: "Bobby" } ​ 1: Object { name: "Jeoff" }`